ElectronJS is not able to detect dual monitor with different X11 DISPLAY value
I have an requirement where I am using dual monitors. Whenever we throw a login UI, one monitor will have login UI while another monitor has blank screen. I am able to achieve though Electron JS.
Above scenario is working fine when DISPLAY value for both monitors is :0. I am able to detect both monitors and able to launch two windows, one for login ui and another to cover monitors.
Working code:
numberOfScreens = screen.getAllDisplays()       // Return two monitor displays
numberOfScreens.forEach((display) => {
  console.log(display.bounds.x)                // Both monitor will have different X and Y values 
  console.log(display.bounds.y)
})

But same code is not working when there are two monitors with two different value for DISPLAY. Which are :0 and :0.1.
numberOfScreens = screen.getAllDisplays()  // Return one monitor display not able to detect another one.
numberOfScreens.forEach((display) => {
  console.log(display.bounds.x)          
  console.log(display.bounds.y)
})

It will be a great help if anyone can provide me solution to cover this use case as well.
Thank you so much in advance.

These are two different screens, if you want to take advantage of them you need to enumerate the screens at the begining. One screen variable won't cut it.

Thanks for responding. what do you mean by enumerating screen. screen object is imported from electron. If possible, can you please provide some code snippets?

I don't know electron but I do know a bit of x11. The x11 terminology is like this. There is a display server (or just display) which can have multiple screens (which are independent disjoint drawing surfaces) and each screen can have multiple monitors attached (a monitor is a viewport into a screen; perhaps it's what electron calls "display".). I assumed that the screen thing in the code represents a screen in the x11 sense, but now I think it's not true. Having more than one screen per display (which is your second setup) is rather unusual in any case. Perhaps don't use this configuration.
